# Run different TeamCity builds on same revision

Tags: teamcity

I have five `TeamCity` builds that are triggered to run at 01:00. Since they all run on the same Agent, in effect they are queued to run one after the other. Each build takes between 10-60 minutes to complete.

What I'd like to guarantee is that all five builds are run on the **same revision**. Currently this is not guaranteed because in case a contributing developer can't fall asleep and decides to commit something at 01:30, all builds that start running after that time will run on a different revision.

**My question:**
Is it possible to configure a build to use a specific VCS revision from a specific time? E.g., configure a build to use the "latest revision at the time of 01:00 today"?

Any other suggestions on how to deal with this problem would be highly appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the builds might be set up to have the others as snapshot dependencies. When that build is triggered (e.g. by schedule trigger), its dependencies will be triggered having VCS revision fixed.

Or even new build configuration might be added, it will do nothing except to triggering its snapshot dependencies (your existing configurations).

Answer (score 0):

You can use independent build(or one of a builds will be a master) configuration with trigger at time you need. New config will starts other configs by PS script which calling REST API "Triggering a Build". You can point specified change for all builds(can be get with API "Get pending changes for a build configuration"). This will guarantee all builds will start with same revision. This way might help if dependencies are unacceptable.